# SQLAlchemy instantiate object from ORM fails with AttributeError: mapper

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've been trying to get a decent-sized project going with SQLAlchemy on the backend. I have table models across multiple files, a declarative base in its own file, and a helper file to wrap common SQLAlchemy functions, and driver file.

I was uploading data, then decided to add a column. Since this is just test data I thought it'd be simplest to just drop all of the tables and start fresh... then when I tried to recreate the schema and tables, the common declarative base class suddenly had empty metadata. I worked around this by importing the class declaration files -- strange, since I didn't need those imports before -- and it was able to recreate the schema successfully.

But now when I try to create objects again, I get an error:

```
AttributeError: mapper
```

Now I'm totally confused! Can someone explain what's happening here? It was working fine before I dropped the schema and now I can't get it working.

Here's the skeleton of my setup:

**base.py**

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()
```

**models1.py**

```
from base import Base
class Business(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'business'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

**models2.py:**

```
from base import Base
class Category(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'category'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

**helper.py:**

```
from base import Base

# I didn't need these two imports the first time I made the schema
# I added them after I was just getting an empty schema from base.Base
# but have no idea why they're needed now?
import models1
import models2

def setupDB():
    engine = getDBEngine(echo=True) # also a wrapped func (omitted for space)
    #instantiate the schema
    try:
        Base.metadata.create_all(engine, checkfirst=True)
        logger.info("Successfully instantiated Database with model schema")
    except:
        logger.error("Failed to instantieate Database with model schema")
        traceback.print_exc()

def dropAllTables():
    engine = getDBEngine(echo=True)
    # drop the schema
    try:
        Base.metadata.reflect(engine, extend_existing=True)
        Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
        logger.info("Successfully dropped all the database tables in the schema")
    except:
        logger.error("Failed to drop all tables")
        traceback.print_exc()
```

**driver.py:**

```
import models1
import models2

# ^ some code to get to this point
categories []
categories.append(
                models2.Category(alias=category['alias'],
                                 title=category['title']) # error occurs here
                )
```

**stack trace: (for completeness)**

```
File "./main.py", line 16, in <module>
yelp.updateDBFromYelpFeed(fname)
  File "/Users/thomaseffland/Development/projects/health/pyhealth/pyhealth/data/sources/yelp.py", line 188, in updateDBFromYelpFeed
    title=category['title'])
  File "<string>", line 2, in __init__
  File "/Users/thomaseffland/.virtualenvs/health/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/instrumentation.py", line 347, in _new_state_if_none
    state = self._state_constructor(instance, self)
  File "/Users/thomaseffland/.virtualenvs/health/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 747, in __get__
    obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = result = self.fget(obj)
  File "/Users/thomaseffland/.virtualenvs/health/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/instrumentation.py", line 177, in _state_constructor
    self.dispatch.first_init(self, self.class_)
  File "/Users/thomaseffland/.virtualenvs/health/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/attr.py", line 256, in __call__
    fn(*args, **kw)
  File "/Users/thomaseffland/.virtualenvs/health/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 2825, in _event_on_first_init
    configure_mappers()
  File "/Users/thomaseffland/.virtualenvs/health/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 2721, in configure_mappers
    mapper._post_configure_properties()
  File "/Users/thomaseffland/.virtualenvs/health/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 1710, in _post_configure_properties
    prop.init()
  File "/Users/thomaseffland/.virtualenvs/health/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/interfaces.py", line 183, in init
    self.do_init()
  File "/Users/thomaseffland/.virtualenvs/health/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1616, in do_init
    self._process_dependent_arguments()
  File "/Users/thomaseffland/.virtualenvs/health/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1673, in     _process_dependent_arguments
    self.target = self.mapper.mapped_table
  File "/Users/thomaseffland/.virtualenvs/health/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 833, in __getattr__
    return self._fallback_getattr(key)
  File "/Users/thomaseffland/.virtualenvs/health/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 811, in _fallback_getattr
    raise AttributeError(key)
AttributeError: mapper
```

I know this post is long, but I wanted to give the complete picture. First I am confused why the `base.Base` schema was empty in the first place. Now I am confused why the Categories object is missing a mapper!

Any help/insight/advice is greatly appreciated, thanks!

**Edit:**

So the model files and `helper.py` are in a supackage and the `driver.py` is actually a file in a sibling subpackage and its code is wrapped in a function.  This driver function is called by a package-level main file.  So I don't think it can be because SQLAlchemy hasn't had time to initialize? (If I understand the answer correctly)  here is what the (relevant part of) main file looks like:

**main.py:**

```
import models.helper as helper
helper.setupDB(echo=true) # SQLAlchemy echos the correct statements

import driverpackage.driver as driver
driver.updateDBFromFile(fname) # error occurs in here
```

and **driver.py** actually looks like:

```
import ..models.models1
import ..models.models2

def updateDBFromFile(fname):
    # ^ some code to get to this point
    categories []
    categories.append(
                    models2.Category(alias=category['alias'],
                                     title=category['title']) # error occurs here
                    )
    # a bunch more code
```

**Edit 2:**
I'm beginning to suspect the underlying issue is the same reason I suddenly need to import all of the models to set up the schema in `helper.py`.  If I print the tables of the imported model objects, they have no bound MetaData or schema:

```
print YelpCategory.__dict__['__table__'].__dict__
####
{'schema': None, '_columns': <sqlalchemy.sql.base.ColumnCollection object at 0x102312ef0>, 
'name': 'yelp_category', 'description': 'yelp_category', 
'dispatch': <sqlalchemy.event.base.DDLEventsDispatch object at 0x10230caf0>, 
'indexes': set([]), 'foreign_keys': set([]), 
'columns': <sqlalchemy.sql.base.ImmutableColumnCollection object at 0x10230fc58>, 
'_prefixes': [], 
'_extra_dependencies': set([]), 
'fullname': 'yelp_category', 'metadata': MetaData(bind=None), 
'implicit_returning': True, 
'constraints': set([PrimaryKeyConstraint(Column('id', Integer(), table=<yelp_category>, primary_key=True, nullable=False))]), 'primary_key': PrimaryKeyConstraint(Column('id', Integer(), table=<yelp_category>, primary_key=True, nullable=False))}
```

I wonder why the metadata from the base that created the database is not gettng bound?

Comment: Is this line in the `Category` class a typo or paste error in the question? `__tablename__ = 'business'`

Comment: Yeah it was, I've fixed it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python SqlAlchemy - AttributeError: mapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45534903/python-sqlalchemy-attributeerror-mapper)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question seems to have died off, so I'll post my work around.  It's simple.  I refactored the code to explicitly supply the classes and the classic mappers, instead of using the declarative base and everything worked fine again...

Answer (score 0):

I guess the error happens because you are executing your code on Python module-level. This code is executed when Python imports the module.

- Move your code to a function.
- Call the function after SQLAlchemy has been properly initialized.
- `create_all()` needs to call only once when the application is installed, because created tables persistent in the database
- You need `DBSession.configure(bind=engine)` or related which will tell models to which database connection they are related. This is missing from the question.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think so? This is example is slightly simplified, in truth the models and driver are in separate subpackages and the driver file is actually a function. An package-level main file calls the driver file. I'll add an edit to explain this properly.

Comment: Added some ideas to the answer.

Comment: I have the ```setupDB() -> create_all``` there to show that SQLAlchemy is loaded and knows about the models, by the time I call ```updateDBFromFile```. In practice that line is commented out.  Also I do have code to get a bound session in ```getDBSession(echo=True)```: this wrapper function configures the engine, and returns ```return sessionmaker(bind=getDBEngine(echo=echo))()```