# Python SqlAlchemy - AttributeError: mapper

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, attributeerror, falconframework

based on my model:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

Base = declarative_base()

class Session(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'sessions'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    token = Column(String(200))
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('app_users.id'))
    user = relationship('model.user.User', back_populates='sessions')
```

I want to instantiate a new session through:

```
session = Session(token='test-token-123')
```

But i get:

```
AttributeError: mapper
```

The full stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/falcon/api.py", line 227, in __call__
    responder(req, resp, **params)
  File "./app_user/register.py", line 13, in on_post
    session = Session(token='test-token-123')
  File "<string>", line 2, in __init__
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/instrumentation.py", line 347, in _new_state_if_none
    state = self._state_constructor(instance, self)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 764, in __get__
    obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = result = self.fget(obj)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/instrumentation.py", line 177, in _state_constructor
    self.dispatch.first_init(self, self.class_)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/attr.py", line 256, in __call__
    fn(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 2976, in _event_on_first_init
    configure_mappers()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 2872, in configure_mappers
    mapper._post_configure_properties()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 1765, in _post_configure_properties
    prop.init()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/interfaces.py", line 184, in init
    self.do_init()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1653, in do_init
    self._process_dependent_arguments()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1710, in _process_dependent_arguments
    self.target = self.mapper.mapped_table
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 850, in __getattr__
    return self._fallback_getattr(key)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 828, in _fallback_getattr
    raise AttributeError(key)
```

I have no idea where this error is coming from and i can not really debug it.. anybody could help me with this issue?

Thanks and Greetings!

Comment: The error is coming from the user relationship configuration, but why is unclear. `self.mapper` is a memoized property of a relationship that resolves the given [argument](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.argument), but for some reason this fails for you with an AttributeError. I'd guess there's some trouble in [resolving the partial path](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/relationships.html#declarative-configuring-relationships) `model.user.User`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44688346/vague-flask-sqlalchemy-error-attributeerror-mapper and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33161280/sqlalchemy-instantiate-object-from-orm-fails-with-attributeerror-mapper

Comment: I suspect you've not imported `model.user.User` class anywhere before you try to instantiate a `Session` object. In other words though the class definition exists, it has not been run. If I for example split your example to `model.base.Base`, `model.session.Session`, a dummy `model.user.User`, and a main function that **only imports `Session`** and tries to use it, the exception is raised. If on the other hand before using the models you import both `Session` and `User` somewhere so that both class definitions are executed, it works.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looking at the traceback you can see these lines:

```
  ...
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1653, in do_init
    self._process_dependent_arguments()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1710, in _process_dependent_arguments
    self.target = self.mapper.mapped_table
  ...
```

which narrow your problem down quite a bit. The relationship

```
    user = relationship('model.user.User', back_populates='sessions')
```

uses a Python evaluable string as the [argument](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.argument), the use of which is further explained in ["Configuring Relationships"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/relationships.html#declarative-configuring-relationships):

> Relationships to other classes are done in the usual way, with the added feature that the class specified to `relationship()` may be a string name. The “class registry” associated with `Base` is used at mapper compilation time to resolve the name into the actual class object, **which is expected to have been defined once the mapper configuration is used**

If you've not imported `models.user` module anywhere before you try to instantiate a `Session` object for the first time, then the name resolving fails because the class `User` has not been created yet and does not exist in the registry. In other words for the name resolving to work, all classes must have been defined, which means that their bodies must have been executed.

And if you actually have imported the `models.user` module, check your other models and that their related model classes have been defined. Using your models for the first time triggers mapper compilation/configuration, so the source of the error could be *other models* as well.